# Algorithm to fill rectangle with small squares?

Tags: algorithm

Given a rectangle with width and height, fill it with n squares (n is integer, also given), such that the squares cover as much of the rectangle's area as possible.
The size of a single square should be returned.

Ideas?

Comment: This looks like homework ... if it is, check this out, might give you a starting place. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem

Comment: No, it's an interview question

Comment: Do the squares have to be the same size? Do they have to be axis-aligned (i.e., have the same orientation as the rectangle)?

Comment: Yes, they are the same size and they have the same orientation as the rectangle.

Comment: This sounds like one of the Dropbox job puzzles: http://www.dropbox.com/jobs/challenges#packing-your-dropbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all the squares are aligned and they are the same size, you can find this by binary searching on the side length of the square:

```
import math

def best_square(w, h, n):
    hi, lo = float(max(w, h)), 0.0
    while abs(hi - lo) > 0.000001:
        mid = (lo+hi)/2.0
        midval = math.floor(w / mid) * math.floor(h / mid)
        if midval >= n:
            lo = mid
        elif midval < n: 
            hi = mid
    return min(w/math.floor(w/lo), h/math.floor(h/lo))
```

Comment: Are you assuming that all n squares are of the same size? The question doesn't seem to mention this.

Comment: Ah!  You are right that I messed up, however it is in fact evident that the sides of the squares must be all equal (otherwise why would it say return the side of the square?).  Where I went wrong was that I assumed they needed to be all aligned to the edges of the rectangle which is not true.  I will leave this solution here since it does solve at least one simpler version of the problem.

Comment: I don't think so.  I tested it out on some of the square cases and it gave the correct solution.  The reason it should go this way is that the number of squares is *decreasing* as a function of the side length, not the other way around.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention in my question, the n squares are the same size, you guys post solutions super fast!

Comment: @Mikola: Hmm… you're right, I think. I've deleted my comment. There seem to be some floating-point errors, though: your code with `print best_square(100, 100, 10)` prints 25.0000007451; perhaps we need a smaller epsilon.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: lol, it seems to be doing a lower bound, not an upper bound...  Anyway, it is an easy fix, you can just divide the side lengths by mid, round and take the min to get the correct result.  I just modified the solution.

Comment: what if you test best_square(10,10,100)? It should return size as 10 and no wasting area, but it seems your code runs forever in this case.

Comment: @xdunder:  I just tried it and got 1.0 for the side length.  Are you sure you are using the right version?

Comment: @Mikola: Hmm..I tested with best_square(3,2,7) and got side length as 1.0, trying to figure out what might go wrong...

Comment: @xdunder:  whoops, that is a rounding error.  I fixed it by changing to the lower bound from the midpoint.

Comment: @Mikola:test it again using case best_square(10,10,100) and got side length as 0.625, guess just replace the lower bound is not enough

Comment: @xdunder: argh.  Ok, I adjusted the binary search again.  It was accidentally terminating early when it got a value which hit n dead on.

Answer (score 6):

The squares do not necessarily have to be oriented the same as the larger rectangle. These sorts of problems are known as packing problems, and finding optimal solutions is notoriously hard.

For an excellent treatment in the case when the larger shape into which the `n` squares are packed is a square, see Erich Friedman's paper [Packing Unit Squares in Squares:
A Survey and New Results](http://www.combinatorics.org/Surveys/ds7.html)

For example, Gödel was the first to publish on this subject. He found that a2+a+3+(a-1)√2 squares can be packed in a square of side a+1+1/√2 by placing a diagonal strip of squares at a 45 degree angle. For example,

[image: Gödel's 5 square solution]

And just for fun, I highly recommend you check out [Erich's Packing Center](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html).

Comment: Do you know if the problem where the squares don't have to be the same size (as the current wording of the question seems to allow) has been considered?

Answer (score 2):

I know that question was a long time ago, but here is what i though :

you have n square
you have a rectangle
you want to know the size of the square to fill the rectangle

for example :

```
rectangle of 1280*720 filled with 100 squares. 
The surface is 1280*720=921600
1 square should have the surface of 921600/100 = 9216
so the square size is sqrt(9216)=96
```

In the end it would just be a function that return the result of this :

```
sqrt((width*height)/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution 
The idea is to go on a recursive loop
Suppose u start with square_counter =0

While length and breath:
// find the biggest possible square

Count1 = length/breath // take the floor

Square_counted += count1

New balance length = length - count1* breath

Now  square with Max size possible wrt breath

Count2 = breath/length

Square_count += count2

Breath = breath - count* length